# Guild is undefined in command handler

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm trying to make a multi-purpose discord bot using discord.js to which is going well, however I'm using a command handler rather than putting all my commands into my main code. Which is causing issues for me as a lot of the variables & consts I need are 'undefined'. I trying to make a kick command which is working somewhat well, but I can't seem to detect if the bot has said permissions to kick a user, all that comes back is that guild is undefined. I tried using `guild.me.hasPermissions("KICK_MEMBERS")` but that didn't work either. Here's my code if anyone can help:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'kick',
description: 'Kick a user from the server.',
guildOnly: true,
permission: 'KICK_MEMBERS',
usage: '<user> <reason>',
execute(message, args) {
    const fullCommand = message.content.substr(1);
    const splitCommand = fullCommand.split(' ');
    const arguments2 = splitCommand.slice(2);

    const reason = arguments2;
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        message.reply('please ping a user for me to kick!');
    }
    if (member.kickable == false) {
        message.channel.send('That user cannot be kicked!');
    }
    if (args.length == 1) {
        member.kick();
    }
    if (args.length > 1) {
        member.kick(reason);
    }
},
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined was pretty clear because you didn't defined them :)

I'm not sure on what version of Discord.JS you are in.

But, If you want to access the guild that the message is sent in, you can use :

```js
let guild = message.guild;
```

After that, you can check your bot permission by using :

```js
guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS");
```

Notes :
I made a custom command handler for my bot that does pass all variable I need as an parameter :

index.js

```js
client.on("message", async message => {

var RawMessage = message.content.split(client.Informasi.get("Konfigurasi").BotInternal.BotSeparator);

// TDCM was the picked command based on what the user want to do.
TDCM.FunctionRun(message, RawMessage, Discord, client, FileSystem);
}
```

TheCommandFunction.js

```js
module.exports = {
    FunctionName: "ping",
    FunctionDeskripsi: "Function description here",
    FunctionInput: "PUBLIC-UNLR",
    FunctionAdminOnly: false,
    async FunctionRun(message, rawmessage, Discord, client, FileSystem) {
        message.reply(`My ping is ${client.ws.ping} ms !`);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check your permissions of the guild object. With a message object, the code would look like this.

```js
message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS");
```

You can read more about the message object [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message).

Comment: I probably didn't make much sense, but I had said that "guild" was coming back as undefined as it wasn't in my main code.

Comment: Did you do "MESSAGE.guild"?